# SSIS Expressions Date Format get just YY for year

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I found many articles on date formatting expressions in SSIS but I couldn't find one that specified how to get just the Year such as 13 for 2013 or 12 for 2012... I tried

```
DATAPART("yy",GETDATE())
```

but it gives me the same result as

```
DATAPART("yyyy",GETDATE())
```

I was thinking of a dirty/hack fix which would be something like

```
DATAPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) - 2000
```

but it just doesn't feel right.... what if someone runs my package 1000 years from now? lol. Any suggestions?

I am trying to add a time stamp to a file name.. so today's file should be Auth040113.txt. I am creating the file name in a variable using expressions.

Comment: Are you looking to do this as part of your source query or as an Expression in a component like a `Derived Column`

Comment: @billinkc it's actually in the Expression property for a Variable in the package

Comment: Why are you doing this if it's just for a log file name? Use the ISO format YYYYMMDD and be done with it. There's almost no reason to use a 2-digit year for new development anymore.

Comment: I know, But I am just trying to conform with the current naming convention that is already in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the modulo operator %: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141815(v=sql.100).aspx

```
DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) % 100
```

Your next problem may be that this will still be be a number and thus will not have leading zeros.

What is your underlying problem?  What are you trying to format a date as?

You would then just use `(DT_WSTR, 2) DATEPART( "YY", GETDATE()) % 100` as part of your expression.

Comment: I am trying to add a time stamp to a file name.. so todays file should be Auth040113.txt.  I am creating the file name in a variable using expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do my datatime formatting for file processing in a script task and save it as a variable to append to the filename.

For example:

```
        //Set date format for folder and file naming
        Dts.Variables["ProcessedDate"].Value = now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Then later I can just add the filename plus my processed date at the end.

But if need be, you could just take the 2 most right of the year after converting it to a string

RIGHT((DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("YYYY" ,GETDATE()), 2)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the mod but it didn't work for me.  However, this worked:

```
substring( (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("YY",GetDate()), 3, 2 )
```